# Int value is different when querying via C# vs azure portal query explorer

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am seeing different the value of an Int64 field change between a query via the C# API vs using the query explorer in the azure portal.

**Document**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "15072358-f9eb-4e92-bde1-18e038484042",
    "messageId": "15072358-f9eb-4e92-bde1-18e038484042",
    "async": true,
    "sequence": 0,
    "sender": "me@direct.example.org",
    "recipient": "you@direct.example.org",
    "transmittedTicks": 636352784545156500,
    "receivedTicks": 636352784546356500,
    "processed": true,
    "id": "15072358-f9eb-4e92-bde1-18e038484042",
    "_rid": "un4kAO--TAABAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/un4kAA==/colls/un4kAO--TAA=/docs/un4kAO--TAABAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00005c09-0000-0000-0000-5963c8bc0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1499711676
  }
]
```

**C# using DocumentDb nuget**

```
var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Expectation>(documentUri)
                  .OrderBy(i=>i.transmittedTicks)
                  .Select(i=>i.transmittedTicks)
                  .AsDocumentQuery();
```

results in the first value as `636352784545156480`

**SQL Query Explorer**

```
SELECT c.transmittedTicks FROM c order by c.transmittedTicks
```

results in the first value as `636352784545156500`

This reads as a precision issue which I see there have been [similar issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/151) in the past.  Are there still outstanding issues or it this expected beahvior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there still outstanding issues or it this expected beahvior?

I also can reproduce the issue that you mentioned.I will report it to Azure  Cosmos DB team. If there is any update, I will update it here.

We could raise an issue on the [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues) or give our [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) to Azure Cosmos DB team.